# How to change "This is required field" message to field-wise magento 2 customer registration

Tags: customer, magento2.3.4, form-validation, ui-form, customer-registration

If I am submitting registration form as blank then all fields are showing an error message:

> This is required field

I want to change this message according to fields.

For Example:

```
> > First name is required
 
> > Last Name is required
 
> > Email is required
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **data-msg-required** attribute in all form fields and you can pass your custom message there.

For ex. for an input field you can use like this..

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" data-msg-required="Firstname is required." data-validate="{required:true}" />
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this is helpful or you need any help, Thanks :-)